# echo numbers changing them one by one

Tags: php, echo

What I am doing:

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();

$i = 0;
foreach($offers as $key => $value){   
i++; 
echo 'number: ' . $i;    
}
```

In page it returns like this:

`number:1number:2number:3` etc....

What I want to do is make it display only the current number:

`number:1`, then in second loop change only 1 to 2... so it should display `number:2` only... and like that...

Is it possible with only php? I have little skill in javascript, jquery.. All help welcome.

Comment: No, PHP is a serverside language. The proccess is in server, and the **final** result will send to browser. So if you need to make client-side interactions you need javascript.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Or he can echo out a `script` tag which runs a function of javascript to change specified element with the `$i`..

Comment: That's javascript, then is the same what I'd say.